# I have a problem with Bootstrap icons all became squre

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-family

After I changed font family on my website the Bootstrap icons gone somone know a way to fix it?
i tried some tips such as add font-weight: 900; write the glyphicon with span out side of the navvar but none of them helped me

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    a.dropbtn {
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-top:20%;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family:'Old English Text MT';
        font-weight: 900;
        color:#f8e2e9;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 25px;
        color:#f8e2e9;
        font-family:'Old English Text MT';    
        font-weight: 900;
    }
</style>
<li runat="server" id="adminstore">
    <a href="UpdateStore.aspx" id="aherf" class="glyphicon-plus expand">UpdateStore</a>
</li>
```

```html
<li runat="server" id="adminstore">
    <a href="UpdateStore.aspx" id="aherf" class="glyphicon-plus expand">UpdateStore</a>
</li>

<style>
    a.dropbtn {
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-top:20%;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family:'Old English Text MT';
        font-weight: 900;
        color:#f8e2e9;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 25px;
        color:#f8e2e9;
        font-family:'Old English Text MT';    
        font-weight: 900;
    }
</style>
```

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FT8D.png)

Comment: show your css and html code.

Comment: @OMiShah i add.

Comment: You're overriding the font-family used by `gylphicon-plus` to create its icons. Use separate elements for the icon and the text.

Comment: see if you can reproduce this issue in a snippet in the question.

Comment: thanks to @HereticMonkey problem solved I really appreciate the help, have a nice day:)